# jQuery - Add class to parent container based on content of child container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to add a class to the outer (parent) container based on the content of a child container. I am able to add a class to the child container based on its content, but If I try to add the class to the parent container, it does it to all of the containers on the page instead of just the current container. Could someone help me update my code so that it only adds the class to the parent container and not all containers that share the same class? Thanks.

jQuery:

```
$('div.promotion-type').each(function () {
    var promotion = $(this).html();
    console.log(promotion);
    if (promotion === "Special Event") {
        $("div.calendar-event").addClass("special-event"); // this is the only one with a class created for it so far
    } else if (promotion === "Daily Promotion") {
        $("div.calendar-event").addClass("daily-promotion");
    }
});
```

HTML: (1 of many containers)

```
<li class="hidden-xs col-sm-6 col-md-4">
  <div class="calendar-event">
    <div class="event-details-container">
      <div class=" col-xs-4 calendar-thumbnail">
      <a href="/warroad-calendar/canadian-day">
        <img src="/_images/warroad/calendar/may-june-2014/canadianDay.jpg" border="0" alt="" />
      </a>
      </div>
      <h3><a href="/warroad-calendar/canadian-day">Canadian Day</a></h3>
      <h4>8 a.m. - 6 p.m.</h4>
      <strong></strong><br />
      <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg promotion-type">Daily Promotion</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Where's the code that sets the class on the container elements ?

Comment: @adeneo I have updated the code to reflect it being added to the parent container, which adds it to all of the containers with that class on the page vs the current container being checked.

Comment: Just use `$(this).closest(".calendar-event")` to get the closest one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

`$("div.calendar-event").addClass("special-event");`

to this:

`$(this).parents("div.calendar-event").addClass("special-event");`

As it appears you already know, using the selector `$("div.calendar-event")` is going to select **all `<div>` elements with the class `calendar-event`**.

By using `$(this).parents("div.calendar-event")`, you're going to look through all parents of the starting `<li>` element, starting with the closest parent and progressing outwards. When it finds the parent that is a `<div>` element with the class `calendar-event`, it's going to call `.addClass()` on that parent element.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are doing a new selection instead of using the current element. Try...

```
$(this).parent().parent().addClass(...);
```

...or possibly...

```
$(this).parents('div.calendar-event').addClass(...);
```

...instead.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this-

```
$("div.calendar-event", this).addClass("special-event");
```

try this:

```
this.find("div.calendar-event").addClass("special-event");
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use text() instead of html()
- remove the classes first
- use $(this)

Code:

```
$('div.promotion-type').each(function () {
    var promotion = $(this).text();
    console.log(promotion);

    $(this).parent().removeClass("special-event");
    $(this).parent().removeClass("daily-promotion");

    $(this).parent().addClass(
           promotion === "Special Event" ? 'special-event': 'daily-promotion');

});
```